# How do I fix buttons, when: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xamarin

Im new in Xamarin. I'm trying to make simple Quizz app, but I got "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error when Layout is changed. I belive buttons and text are null for some reason, but I cant fix it

I tried to catch a null buttons with try-catch, but it dosent work

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using Android.App;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Text;
using Android.Views;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;



namespace Tasak.Xamarin
{
    [Activity(Label = "Tasak")]
    public class gra : Activity
    {
       TextView wynik, text, response,
            pytanie, odpA, odpB, odpC, odpD, Time;

        Button button1, button2, button3, button4, menu;
        EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort, editTextPin, editTextNick;
        Button buttonConnect, buttonClear;
        MyRunnable run;
        public string connid;
        HubConnection hubConn;
        int Port = 0; string Adres = "", Pin = "", Nick = "";
        string guz = "";
        int here = 3;//layout:  0 - menu, 1- game, 2- scores 
        bool answered = false; 

        public string logi = "", answer = "", receivestr = "bad", endpoint = "";
        private Thread proba;
        public int maxtime, nr_pytania, score;

        //First to run 
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setdata_menu();
        }


        Button clickAction(Button t)
        {
            guz = t.Text;//Witch button is pressed
            if (t.Text == menu.Text) setdata_menu();
            else if (!answered)
            { answer = guz; response.Text += "answered"; t.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White); answered = true; }
            response.Text += guz;
            guz = "";
            return t;
        }

        void setdata_menu()
        {
            if (here != 0) { here = 0;  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main); }

            // Get our UI controls from the loaded layout
            editTextAddress = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addressEditText);
            editTextPort = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.portEditText);
            editTextPin = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.pinEditText);
            editTextNick = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.nickEditText);

            buttonConnect = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.connectButton);
            buttonClear = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.clearButton);
            response = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.responseTextView);
            response = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.log);

            try { response.Text = logi; }

            catch { response.Text = ""; }

            buttonConnect.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    //from edittext
                    Port = System.Convert.ToInt32(editTextPort.Text);
                    Adres = editTextAddress.Text;
                    Pin = editTextPin.Text;
                    Nick = editTextNick.Text;

                    //connection start
                    try
                    {
                        run = new MyRunnable(this);
                        run.Run();
                        setup_conn(); //connects to API and starts a fake game,

                    }
                    catch (Exception f) { response.Text = f.Message; }
                }
                catch { response.Text = ("Zły Parametr"); }
            };

            buttonClear.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                response.Text = "";
                editTextAddress.Text = ""; editTextPin.Text = "";
                editTextPort.Text = ""; editTextNick.Text = "";
            };
        }

        void fake_game()
        {
            logi += "waiting for game to start...\n";
            RunOnUiThread(() =>  response.Text = logi);
            start_question("pyt1?");
        }

        public void start_question(string questions_answers)
        {

            setdata_game();
            response.Text = logi+" hello\n";

            text.Text = ("Pytanie " + nr_pytania);
            wynik.Text = ("Wynik\n" + score);


            answered = false;
            logi = "";
            nr_pytania++;
            logi += "pyt " + nr_pytania + "\n";

        }

        void setdata_game()
        {

            //Layout change - Doesnt work yet
            if (here != 1) { here = 1; RunOnUiThread(() => SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_gra)); }
            logi += "layout\n";


            text = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text);
            wynik = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.wynik);
            response = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.responseTextView);
            pytanie = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Question);
            odpA = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.odpA);
            odpB = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.odpB);
            odpC = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.odpC);
            odpD = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.odpD);
            Time = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Time);

            button1 = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            button2 = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
            button3 = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button3);
            button4 = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button4);
            menu = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.menu);



                text.SetTextColor(Color.White);
                wynik.SetTextColor(Color.White);
                response.SetTextColor(Color.White);
                pytanie.SetTextColor(Color.White);
                odpA.SetTextColor(Color.White);
                odpB.SetTextColor(Color.White);
                odpC.SetTextColor(Color.White);
                odpD.SetTextColor(Color.White);
                Time.SetTextColor(Color.White);

                button1.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Gray);
                button2.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Gray);
                button3.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Gray);
                button4.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Gray);
                menu.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Gray);

                button1.SetTextColor(Color.White);
                button2.SetTextColor(Color.White);
                button3.SetTextColor(Color.White);
                button4.SetTextColor(Color.White);
                menu.SetTextColor(Color.White);

                // doesnt work yet
                button1.Click += (sender, e) => button1 = clickAction(button1);
                button2.Click += (sender, e) => button2 = clickAction(button2);
                button3.Click += (sender, e) => button3 = clickAction(button3);
                button4.Click += (sender, e) => button4 = clickAction(button4);
                menu.Click += (sender, e) => menu = clickAction(menu);

                logi += "pytanie1\n"; response.Text = logi;


        }
```

````
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".gra">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="561dp"
        android:layout_height="557dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/question2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="3dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Pytanie "
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="A"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Question"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="B"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="C"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="D"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wynik"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:text="Wynik\n0"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:text="menu"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/responseTextView"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="323dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Question" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Time"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.474"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Question"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:text="Question"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Time"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/odpA"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="a"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Question" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/odpB"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="b"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/odpA" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/odpC"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="c"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/odpB" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/odpD"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="d"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/odpC" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>```

Buttons and text are inactive and different colour then in .axml file
````

Comment: Delete the folder `bin` and `obj` of share project and Android project,then clean and rebuild. If it still doesn't work, you can share a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: Didnt work, but error is now in different place then it was before. Im sending a google drive link with this part of program [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pZxOZYRoImzMeB2qQ5ag21fm7yUN3IsB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Don't forget to remove your personal info before you upload it,such as userid ,password or account id.

Comment: All info in that code are samples, data base is not connected yet, and I changed IP adresses to random ones, dont know if I could do anything more, Im really new in this

Comment: OK ,I will check it.

Comment: Activity findViewById() searches the activity's view hierarchy set with setContentView() for the given view id. So in `onCreat()` you should firstly setcontentView before you call `setdata_menu();`.

Comment: I add SetcontentView into my onCreate(), yet error still appears at setdata_game() when I try to show text on screen. Im not sure if I should change layout by RunOnUiThread(), could it be a problem here?

Comment: Yes, update UI in main thread .